# ArcGIS Pro crashes when running "create scene layer package" without CRS transformation

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, arcgis-online

I have a 3D scene file that I need to save as a scene layer package to use it in ArcGIS Online. My portal does not allowing uploading it as a web scene directly. The tool "create scene layer package" works when I transform the CRS of the file. However, this mustn't be transformed, as the file is already in the correct CRS. When I enter the current CRS, and thus opt not to change the CRS, the tool always crashes before finishing, with the "arcgis encountered a serious crash" window. Any possible work-around?

EDIT: it seems that the tool simply does not support Amersfoort (RD New) CRS, because projecting other layers to this CRS in the create scene layer package tool makes ArcGIS crash as well!

[image]

Comment: Can you copy-modify an existing coordinate system based on the same datum?  Otherwise you might be able to add the CRS to Pro by importing it from the layer presenting the problem.

Comment: what version of Pro are you using?